# ember-cli specify which div to render applicaiton in

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

How do you tell ember to render the app inside a specific div on the page? Right now it gets appended to the end of `body`. I am using ember-cli.

Is it done somehow in `config/environment.js`?

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'app',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [rootElement property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_rootElement). With Ember-CLI, edit `app/app.js` and add it to the Application object.

```
var App = Ember.Application.extend({
    rootElement: '#ember-app'
});
```